# Close Tkinter window while using try and except. (Window variable is self)

Tags: python, tkinter

What I want my code to do, is when any exception happens it should close the program and allow me to call a function which opens up the "program has crashed".

When using a try and except around the whole program, I can't access my self variable inside the except because it's created inside the try
so, I'm trying by putting the try and except inside each class

The current error I get is this: "TclError: bad window path name ".!frame.!startpage"

I added a copy of the code below. (My full program is 6000 lines, this is a shortened down version of 100 lines to figure out the issue)

```
Save New Duplicate & Edit Just Text Twitter
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)
Information_Font = ("Verdana", 10)

new = ""

class Application(tk.Tk):                         
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs, ):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Title")
        

        container = tk.Frame(self, width=1768, height=20000)
        container.pack(side="top", fill='both' , expand = 1)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.geometry("500x500")
        self.title("Program Title")

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame
            #frame.pack()
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
            
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        frame.tkraise()
        
        frame.update()
        frame.event_generate("<<ShowFrame>>")
        

class StartPage(tk.Frame,):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        try:
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
            label = ttk.Label(self, text="Start Page/Please Login", font=LARGE_FONT)
            label.pack(pady=0,padx=100)
            
            labelempty = ttk.Label(self, text="", font=LARGE_FONT)
            labelempty.pack(pady=12,padx=100)
            
            ConsolePasswordeLabel = Label(self, text="Console Password")
            ConsolePasswordeLabel.pack(side = "top", pady=10,padx=10)
            Console = StringVar()
            ConsoleEntry = Entry(self, show = "*", textvariable=Console).pack(pady=2,padx=2)
            
            EnablePasswordeLabel = Label(self, text="Enable Password")
            EnablePasswordeLabel.pack(side = "top", pady=10,padx=10)
            Enable = StringVar()
            EnableEntry = Entry(self, show = "*", textvariable=Enable).pack(pady=2,padx=2)
            
            def login():
                Enable1 = Enable.get()
                Console1 = Console.get()
                print(Console1)
                print(Enable1)
            
            def dologin():
                login()
                controller.show_frame(PageOne)
            
            def showpasswords():
                pass            
    
            Login = tk.Button(self, text ="Login", command= dologin)
            Login.pack(padx = 10, pady = 10)    
            Login.place(x = "260", y = "220", width = "90")
            
            ShowButton = tk.Button(self, text ="Show passwords", command= "") 
            ShowButton.pack(padx = 10, pady = 10)
            ShowButton.place(x = "140", y = "220")
            print(ABCD) # Raising an error on purpose to test the try and except
        except:
            print("Excepting")
            self.destroy()
            print("1. Program should have closed")
            print('2. "Program has crashed" page can now be opened, from seperate mainloop"')


class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text="Switchport Menu", font=LARGE_FONT,) #background="red")
        label.pack(pady=0,padx=100)    
        
app = Application()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `report_callback_exception` method of `Tk` class, e.g.:

```
from tkinter import messagebox

class Application(tk.Tk):    
    ...

    def report_callback_exception(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        # The following line is optional, it will print info about the exception to the console (the default tkinter behaviour)
        super().report_callback_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)

        filename, line, *_ = traceback.extract_tb(exc_traceback).pop()
        messagebox.showerror(
            "Program has crashed",
            f"{exc_type.__name__}: {exc_value}\n"
            f"{filename}, Line: {line}"
        )
        self.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you, Do I then call that function inside any class where I place a try and except?

Comment: Just override the method, and it will catch all exceptions (at least in your application), you don't need even add try-except anywhere.

Comment: In short, tkinter itself catches all exceptions, which occur in event and command handlers, or other functions which are called from handlers, and then calls `report_callback_exception` method to print them. So basically to catch all exceptions in your application you just need to override this method.